# Add custom attributes to a choice widget

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a choice list (assuming Red, Blue and Yellow). Each one of those choices has a color (guess :).

Is it possible to set the color css property of each option box, assuming that I'm using 'expandable' field option ? I'm ok for modifying the field theme if mandatory (an optimal solution would create a new field type inheriting from the choice widget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your choice list code is something like this..

```
$builder->add('Colors', 'choice', array(
  'choices'   => array(
       'red'=>'red',
       'blue'=>'blue',
       'yellow','yellow'
  ),
'required'  => true,'label'=>'colors:'
));
```

your requirement can be easily satisfied by just using css

**CSS**

```
option[value="red"] {
    background-color: red;
}

option[value="blue"] {
    background-color: blue;
}

option[value="yellow"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

hope you expected this result..